# VBS. Add header to specific Excel document

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to amend the below code so it adds the headers to specific Excel document and closes it once it has added the headers. The script keeps dying on row two and being new to vba I'm not sure what I ahve done wrong

```
Sub AddHeaders()

    Dim headers() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn this off for the macro to run a little faster

    Set wb = "C:\Users\aallen\Documents\Reports\PW Infor\pw.xlsx"

    headers() = Array("Superhero", "City", "State", "Country", "Publisher", "Demographics", _
        "Planet", "Flying Abilities", "Vehicle", "Sidekick", "Powers")
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        With ws
        .Rows(1).Value = "" 'This will clear out row 1
        For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
            .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
        Next i
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        End With
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

    MsgBox ("Done!")

End Sub
```

Comment: For a start VBScript is typeless any reference to `As Type` will cause a syntax error. If you are asking about doing this in VBScript but only post a really poor VBA example, the question is clearly too broad. Please review [ask] before posting on [so].

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to say that the code of the question is VBA but @AlexAllen wanted to do it with VBScript. So we have 2 different approaches now.

---

### 1. Approach: VBA

You should make use of the [Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx).

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & Filename
```

in your case

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\aallen\Documents\Reports\PW Infor\pw.xlsx")
```

to be independent from the username and always load it from the current users folder you can use

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Environ("userprofile") & "\Documents\Reports\PW Infor\pw.xlsx")
```

---

Side note:

- Don't forget to close the workbook with `wb.Close SaveChanges:=True`.
- I also recommend to use `Option Explicit` so you don't forget to declare any variables like you did with `i` (`Dim i as Long`).

#### So we end up with …

```
Sub AddHeaders()
    Dim headers() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i as Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn this off for the macro to run a little faster

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\aallen\Documents\Reports\PW Infor\pw.xlsx")

    headers() = Array("Superhero", "City", "State", "Country", "Publisher", "Demographics", _
        "Planet", "Flying Abilities", "Vehicle", "Sidekick", "Powers")
    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        With ws
            .Rows(1).Value = "" 'This will clear out row 1
            For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
                .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
            Next i
            .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        End With
    Next ws
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

    MsgBox ("Done!")
End Sub
```

---

### 2. Approach: VBScript

```
call AddHeaders

Sub AddHeaders()
    Dim xlApp, xlWbk, xlSht
    Dim headers 
    Dim i

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'we should prevent any alerts from excel so nothing stops that script.
    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False 'turn this off for the macro to run a little faster

    Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\aallen\Documents\Reports\PW Infor\pw.xlsx")

    headers = Array("Superhero", "City", "State", "Country", "Publisher", "Demographics", _
            "Planet", "Flying Abilities", "Vehicle", "Sidekick", "Powers")
    For Each xlSht In xlWbk.Sheets
        With xlSht
            .Rows(1).Value = "" 'This will clear out row 1
            For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
                .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
            Next
            .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
        End With
    Next
    
    xlWbk.Close (True)
    xlApp.Quit

    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox ("Done!")
    
    'always deallocate after use...
    Set xlSht = Nothing
    Set xlWbk = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: hi Peh, I changed  Set wb = "C:\Users\aallen\Documents\Reports\PW Infor\pw.xlsx" to Set wb = Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\aallen\Documents\Reports\PW Infor\pw.xlsx" But still getting a error at row 2

Comment: @AlexAllen Sorry, I missed the brackets. See updated answer. What do you mean when you say row 2?

Comment: Apologies If i used the wrong wording. Error Script Host. Script: Location of Script.  Line: 2, Char: 15 Error: Expected end of statement, Code: 800A0401, Source: Microsoft VBScript Compilation error..     Just had a thought do I not have to specify the sheet that I want to add the headers too?

Comment: Do you have this `Sub AddHeaders()` within another Excel file (VBA) or within a VBScript (VBS) this is a huge difference (VBA is not VBScript). This Sub is VBA code and needs to be within an Excel file (Alt + F11 to open the VBA-Editor) you cannot run this as a VBScript that would be a complete different approach.

Comment: Hi Peh,  Ahh Sorry to be a pain but is there any chance you would be able to demonstrate the difference. Being new to the scripting world just interested in seeing how a code that basically does the same thing would appear in VBA vs VBS

Comment: @AlexAllen So now you should see how it could look like a VBScript too.